# Problem with some specific indefinite integral solved with Wolfram Alpha online integrator

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Looking for solution to integral below I have found on Wolfram Alpha that result
\begin{equation}
\int{\sqrt{\frac{1+2x}{(1+x)^3 (1-ax)}}} dx=-i~2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+a}}~E\Bigg(\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{1+a}{a (1+x)}}}, \frac{a}{2+2 a}\Bigg). \tag{1}
\end{equation}
However, because my argument in $arcsin$ function is always greater as $1$ the result of integration (right side of equation 1) is a complex number what cannot be true. The variable $x$ and parameter $a$ are positive and less or equal $1$, i.e. the integrand is a positive real function. How to solve that problem?

Comment: I believe one thing to be wary of is how the right side is not expressed in terms of $x$ despite the left side being an integral with respect to $x$. May you double-check your work? [WA is giving something completely different.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+sqrt%28%281%2B2x%29%2F%28%281%2Bx%29%5E3+%281-ax%29%29%29)

Comment: @Accelerator I do not understand you. The right side is a function of $x$ and is identical with expression in your link section „Alternate forms assuming a and x are positive“.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem described above is to realize that an indefinite integral can be determined only up to some arbitrary constant. As it happens
the expression on the right side of equation $(1)$ is the sum of imaginary constant and a real function. Thus, an appropriate choice of integration constant can make the result a real function, as showed below
\begin{equation}
\int{\sqrt{\frac{1+2x}{(1+x)^3 (1-ax)}}} dx=-i~2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+a}}~E\Bigg(\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{1+a}{a (1+x)}}}, \frac{a}{2+2 a}\Bigg)+~i~2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+a}}~E\Bigg(\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{1+a}{a (1+x_0)}}}, \frac{a}{2+2 a}\Bigg) \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $x_0$ is an arbitrary chosen value of the integration variable.